# Redirection of Suspended users in Moodle to a custom page

Tags: php, customization, moodle

I want to redirect my suspended users to a custom html page when they click the login button. These students have issues with accounting so we need to let them know somehow by customizing the login button.
Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to modify `login/index.php`, around the line `if ($errorcode == AUTH_LOGIN_UNAUTHORISED) {`, by adding the relevant if case:

```
            if ($errorcode == AUTH_LOGIN_UNAUTHORISED) {
                //...
            } else if ($errorcode == AUTH_LOGIN_SUSPENDED) {
                redirect('https://www.google.es'); // redirect here!
            } else {
                // ...
            }
```

I would not recommend to directly change the `login/index.php` code, though and using customscripts (https://docs.moodle.org/dev/customscripts) to replace the `index.php` entry point with a modified one could be equally harder to maintain when you upgrade your Moodle to later versions.